# How do I make the number automatically double inside the textbox every minute

Tags: c#

In c# I made the timer add a number to the text box every minute. But every minute it adds the same number you specified I want to make the number double inside the same text box every minute. For example, in the first minute, a number 5 was added. In the second minute, I want it to reach 10, and in the third minute to 15, and so on every minute until it reaches a number I specified in a second text box and stops. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? Are you probably using a particular UI tier like `ASP.Net` or `WPF`?

Answer (score 0):

Check again where you update the value inside the textbox, if you have set it up good it will probably look something like this:

```
//timer code
//When timer triggered
if(int.TryParse(textBox.Text))    
{
int tempValue = int.Parse(textBox.Text);
tempValue += 5;

textBox.Text = tempValue.ToString();
}
else
{
//If it's not a integer do something
}
```

One possible problem is that when you go and update the value inside the textBox you forgot to append the value and instead you just replaced it with a new one, let me know if I understood the question the right way